# .gitignore for asp.net razor project

Tags: asp.net, git, razor

I'm learning asp.net core 2.0 and I've created a new project with the command `dotnet new razor -o myworkingdir`.

I want to put this project into a git repository, and I'd like to know what I have to write into the `.gitignore` file in order to avoid to commit useless things.

What's an example of a `.gitignore` file for a new asp.net Razor project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This GitHub repo has a good collection of .gitignore files you can download and modify for your specific needs as they arise.

https://github.com/github/gitignore

You would use https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore in particular.